# Same name class element

Tags: element

How do i change 2 class "myDiv" span name at the same time? Below script only work for the first "myDiv"

```
<div class="myDIV">
  <span>orginial name1</span>
</div>

<div class="myDIV">
  <span>orginial name2</span>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
    x[0].innerHTML = "<span>new name for all</span>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, just apply the change to all. Take a look e.g. at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
```

will give array of elements, you are referring to only first element by [0].

update your function as below to change in both.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
    x[0].innerHTML = "<span>new name for all</span>";
    x[1].innerHTML = "<span>new name for all</span>";
}
```

Alternatively you can use jquery to achieve it in just one line.

```
 $('.myDIV').html("<span>new name for all</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is working for the first one,then this should work for second one

```
  function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
   x[0].innerHTML = "<span>new name for all</span>";
   x[1].innerHTML = "<span>new name for all</span>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A little simple things sometimes forgotten, this simply by adding `x[1].innerHTML = "<span>new name for all 2</span>";`

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
    x[0].innerHTML = "<span>new name for all 1</span>";
    x[1].innerHTML = "<span>new name for all 2</span>";
}
```

```html
<div class="myDIV">
  <span>orginial name1</span>
</div>

<div class="myDIV">
  <span>orginial name2</span>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```